# GraphView y-axis label flicker and space on top with empty title?

Tags: android, android-graphview

Two questions regarding the GraphView library.

1) With manual setNumVerticalLabels set when switching from scrolling to scaling and vice versa, that the labels for my y-Axis change it's position. In scrolling mode they are closer together and in scaling mode a bit further apart.
In case of having the number of labels set automatically, the number of labels also changes between the two modes.

Is this a known bug? Is there any way to get around that behavior?

2) Is it possible to claim the space above the graph for the graph if the title is left empty?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) that is because your labels could need more space. You have 2 options:

- a) set a fixed width for the vertical labels
- or b) make sure that the labels have a fixed/limited count of characters via custom label formatter.

2) this is not possible with GraphView 3.x, but in GraphView 4.0 this is be fixed.